# how did babel not working in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js, babeljs

I currently use following code to retrieve data in Node express 4.x. However there is a problem confused me

```
//models/User/User.js
import allUserName from './functions/allUserName';
module.export = function (sequelize,DataTypes){
    const User = sequelize.define('User',{
     id:......,
     ..........},{
     tableName:'user',
     classMethods:{
           associate:function(models){
           //assocoation.....},
           allUserName:allUserName(this)
     }
   return User;
}

//in models/User/functions/allUserName.js
    export default async function(model){
          //some code 
          return result;
    }
//in app.js
import models from '../../models/';
const user = require('express').Router();
user.get(...........,async function(req,res){
   let list = await models.User.allUserName(models.User);
    if(list){
        res.status(200).send(list);
    }else{
        res.sendStatus(500)
    }
})
```

When I use `babel lib -d dist` and then `node ./dist/app.js` in bash, I see  the error like:

```
 /root/api/lib/models/User/User.js:8
 import allUserID  from './functions/allUserID';
 ^^^^^^
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
 at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
 .....
```

if I change import to const

```
  const allUserName = require(....);
//no error but app.js says models.User.allUserName is not a function...
```

but if I change to following code it works fine!

```
    module.export = function (sequelize,DataTypes){
    const User = sequelize.define('User',{
     id:......,
     ..........},{
     tableName:'user',
     classMethods:{
           associate:function(models){
           //assocoation.....},
           allUserName:async function(){
              let list = await this.findAll({...})
              return list;
           }
     }
   return User;
}
```

can any one tell me why this error happen? I installed babel and related plugins, other function are working fine until I wrote User model in this way.

Comment: Have you actually *used* Babel to transpile your files?

Comment: yes my babelrc is  
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2"],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-runtime", {
      "polyfill": false,
      "regenerator": true
    }]
  ]
}

Comment: Did you transpile via CLI?

Comment: no , I installed babel-cli but I don't know how to transpile automatically via CLI, I may have a try later

Comment: how did you installed `babel-cli`?, Please share the result of the command you have been using `babel lib -d dist `. Better try this, `./node_modules/.bin/babel src -d lib`.

Comment: I use npm -i babel-cli --s and got     "babel-cli": "^6.22.2" in package .json@RaghavGarg

    babel lib -d dist

  lib/app.js -> dist/app.js
  lib/configs/appConf.js -> dist/configs/appConf.js
  lib/configs/database.js -> dist/configs/database.js
  lib/configs/models.js -> dist/configs/models.js
 ........
I didn't have src ,lib is where the whole src code

Comment: Please follow [these steps](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation) and see if it works for you. Actually, I want you to try npm script for this task.
Just to be sure you did run this command `npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev` right? Also you should use command like `npm install babel-cli --save-dev` to save it as an dev dependency.

Comment: @RaghavGarg it solved my problems thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like, you have added presets to `.babelrc`, but didn't install them using npm. Please install the relevant presets with the command:

```
npm install babel-preset-<your preset> --save-dev
```

Also, please use babel using the npm script, add the below line inside your `package.json` under the scripts.

```
"build": "babel lib -d dist"
```

and use it like `npm run build`, because babel is installed in your project and your OS doesn't know about `babel`. So only npm can access the babel. Hence we will ask npm to run babel commands using npm scripts.

**Reference:** [Using Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup#installation)

**Note:** Please install babel with the command `npm install babel-cli --save-dev` to save it as a dev dependency and locally to your project.

> While you can install Babel CLI globally on your machine, it’s much better to install it locally project by project.